# Csv file only store single row pf data using python

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I scrape a website and try to store it into Csv format  but when  i did it is store only single row of data.

how to write multiples Row of data in csv.

```
 for lis in lists:
        title = lis.find('a', class_="title").text
        tag = lis.find('span', class_="etc-mark").text
        datetime = lis.find('span', class_="datetime").text
        address = lis.find('div', class_="middle-xs").text
        img = lis.find('span', class_="https://thecryptobasic.com")

        data = [title, tag, datetime,address,img]

        print(data)
        
 

# create the csv writer
writer = csv.writer(f)

# write a row to the csv file
writer.writerow(header)

writer.writerow(data)
 

# close the file
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

`data` gets overwritten in every iteration, so after the loop it contains the data from the last iteration only.

1. Initialize `data` before the loop, the append to it in every iteration.
2. Use `writerows` instead of `writerow`.

```py
data = []

for lis in lists:
    title = lis.find('a', class_="title").text
    tag = lis.find('span', class_="etc-mark").text
    datetime = lis.find('span', class_="datetime").text
    address = lis.find('div', class_="middle-xs").text
    img = lis.find('span', class_="https://thecryptobasic.com")

    data.append([title, tag, datetime, address, img])

...

writer.writerows(data)
```

while refactoring this piece of code, it will also better to let `with` manage the opening and closing of the file:

```py
...

with open(..., 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

We can even merge the `write` calls by pre-initializing `data` with `header`:

```py
data = [header]

for lis in lists:
    title = lis.find('a', class_="title").text
    tag = lis.find('span', class_="etc-mark").text
    datetime = lis.find('span', class_="datetime").text
    address = lis.find('div', class_="middle-xs").text
    img = lis.find('span', class_="https://thecryptobasic.com")

    data.append([title, tag, datetime, address, img])

with open(..., 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Am sorry to say, Its return same output.

Comment: Again it returns single row

Comment: @AbdulRehman You either implemented it wrong or `lists` actually contains a single element

Comment: i just copy and past as it is.

Comment: Am trying to fix this from  6 hours

Comment: The fix/solution here looks the same as this one, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74223209/246801 (minus the Pandas change)